# Convert Pandas rows into a matrix of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I want to convert each row from a pandas dataframe into an array, and then create a matrix with them.

I know how to do it with columns:

```
X = np.matrix([df['colA'].values,
 df['ColB'].values])
```

How can I do it by columns?

More details:

this is a sample of my dataframe:
[image]

The output I want is this (please do not pay attention to the digits now):

```
[[36.10062, -115.2948],  #row 0
 [36.10062, -116.2948],  #row 1
 [34.10062, -112.2948],  #row 2
 [38.10062, -111.2948]]  #row 3
```

Comment: `X = df.values`. It's already going to become a 2D matrix.

Comment: @raganjosh I need a matrix of array such as matrix([[[1,1],[3,5]], [[3,2],[3,2]]])

Comment: Perhaps if you add a small sample your issue becomes clearer

Comment: You'll need to provide example input and example output if my suggestion doesn't work. Also note that `np.matrix` has been floating just above deprecation for years now; they don't want people using it because you can do everything with an `array`

Comment: Can you provide [MCVE]

Comment: You can pass numpy array to matrix, np.matrix(df.values) or np.matrix(df.values.T) depending on alignment you want

Comment: I've added some more details, thanks

Comment: I believe you want `df[['colA', 'colB']].values`, it you want them as a matrix do `np.asmatrix(df[['colA', 'colB']].values)`

Comment: Why does it have to be `np.matrix`?  Why not a 2d `ndarray`?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas dataframe already have solution for this.

```
df.values
```